# Add an XML files content inside another XML document dynamically in Android using Eclipse

Tags: android, android-layout

I'm very new to Android Development and I'd like to add a page to another dynamically. I'm a C# web developer and would like to do the same as using a Master Page and inserting other pages in this page.

The code I have at the moment is as follow: (Keep in mind that I've never done this, and any and all advise would be appreciated.)

I Have 3 main documents I'm working on at the moment:
Pharma Manifest.xml
MainActivity.java
fragment_main_dummy.xml(I'm using the dummy since it's already doing what I want.)

Here is the content on MainActivity.xml

```
package com.pharma.pharma;

import org.w3c.dom.Text;

import android.annotation.TargetApi;
import android.app.ActionBar;
import android.location.Address;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Build;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.support.v4.app.NavUtils;
import android.view.Gravity;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity implements
        ActionBar.OnNavigationListener {

    /**
     * The serialization (saved instance state) Bundle key representing the
     * current dropdown position.
     */
    private static final String STATE_SELECTED_NAVIGATION_ITEM = "selected_navigation_item";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        // Set up the action bar to show a dropdown list.
        final ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
        actionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
        actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_LIST);

        // Set up the dropdown list navigation in the action bar.
        actionBar.setListNavigationCallbacks(
        // Specify a SpinnerAdapter to populate the dropdown list.
                new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActionBarThemedContextCompat(),
                        android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,
                        android.R.id.text1, new String[] {
                                getString(R.string.title_Dashboard),
                                getString(R.string.title_Customers),
                                getString(R.string.title_Products),
                                getString(R.string.title_Detailing),
                                getString(R.string.title_Appointments),
                                getString(R.string.title_Events), }), this);
    }

    /**
     * Backward-compatible version of {@link ActionBar#getThemedContext()} that
     * simply returns the {@link android.app.Activity} if
     * <code>getThemedContext</code> is unavailable.
     */
    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.ICE_CREAM_SANDWICH)
    private Context getActionBarThemedContextCompat() {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.ICE_CREAM_SANDWICH) {
            return getActionBar().getThemedContext();
        } else {
            return this;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Restore the previously serialized current dropdown position.
        if (savedInstanceState.containsKey(STATE_SELECTED_NAVIGATION_ITEM)) {
            getActionBar().setSelectedNavigationItem(
                    savedInstanceState.getInt(STATE_SELECTED_NAVIGATION_ITEM));
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        // Serialize the current dropdown position.
        outState.putInt(STATE_SELECTED_NAVIGATION_ITEM, getActionBar()
                .getSelectedNavigationIndex());
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(int position, long id) {
        // When the given dropdown item is selected, show its contents in the
        // container view.
        Fragment fragment = new DummySectionFragment();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putInt(DummySectionFragment.ARG_SECTION_NUMBER, position + 1);
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .replace(R.id.container, fragment).commit();
        return true;
    }

    /**
     * A dummy fragment representing a section of the app, but that simply
     * displays dummy text.
     */
    public static class DummySectionFragment extends Fragment {
        /**
         * The fragment argument representing the section number for this
         * fragment.
         */
        public static final String ARG_SECTION_NUMBER = "section_number";

        public DummySectionFragment() {
        }

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main_dummy, container, false);

            TextView dummyTextView = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.section_label);
            dummyTextView.setText(Integer.toString(getArguments().getInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER)));

            switch(getArguments().getInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER)){
            case 1:
                dummyTextView.setText("blah Blah Dashboard");
                break;
            case 2:
                dummyTextView.setText("blah Blah Customers");
                break;
            case 3:
                dummyTextView.setText("blah Blah Products");
                break;
            case 4:
                dummyTextView.setText("blah Blah Detailing");
                break;
            case 5:
                dummyTextView.setText("blah Blah Appointments");
                break;
            case 6:
                //Insert XML to fragment dummy here as a test
                break;
                default:
                    //throw error
            }
            return rootView;
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the code in the Manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.pharma.pharma"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="11"
        android:targetSdkVersion="17" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.pharma.pharma.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

And lastly the code for fragment_main_dummy.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".MainActivity$DummySectionFragment" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/section_label"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textIsSelectable="true" />

    <include
        android:id="@+id/section_layout"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        layout="@layout/dashboard" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

I've sat with this for days.

I'm still new at this and can't figure it out. I'm also pressured to get this whole project done in about a months time. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your title is conceptually wrong, you don't one XML to another. Those XML are heavily crunched  and pre-compiled during the compile time and don't exist as you see them in the final app.

Further, those XML are just representations for the system to build `Views` and inside `ViewGroups` which is a class that `extends View` you can call `.addView(view);`

The `include` xml code you use, is a good way to re-use static generated XML, but for dynamic generated stuff you need to do it via code.

I've notice you're using fragments stuff. So probably you're better use the Fragment route of dynamically adding/removing stuff

The code you created inside `onNavigationItemSelected` is pretty much everything you need to do to dynamically change stuff around.

The fragment you're creating/instantiating will override `onCreateView` to inflate a new View and return it. That new view will be inserted on `android.R.id.content` (that is the View ID for your whole content) or for any ID that you specified in your XML.

hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

You could use LayoutInflater to do that.

eg.

```
RelativeLayout relativeLayout= (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.relativeLayout);

LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

relativeLayout.addView(childIndex, layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.newLayoutToAdd, this, false) );
```